# MongoDB Pymongo copy a whole collection to another

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have 10,000 data in a collection and want to copy the whole thing to another collection.

I'm new to mongodb and were stuck here for a while and am looking for a help.

I've tried

```
for a in db.source_file.find():
        try:
            db.destination.insert(a) // tried insert_one here too
        except:
            print('did not copy')
```

nothing copies and kept printing out "did not copy"

I also have  tried this

```
SOURCE = db.source_file
DESTINATION = db.destination

pipeline = [ {"$match": {}}, 
             {"$out": "DESTINATION" },
]

SOURCE.aggregate(pipeline)
```

This didn't copy anything either

The source collection definitely contains data as when I tried source_col.find_one(), it prints out the data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `db.command()` function?
Something like this should work.

```py
db.command('eval', 'db.collection.copyTo("newcollection")', nolock=True)
```

Comment: Another thing poped in my head. Have you tried printing out the error to see what went wrong?            
 ```
try:
    #some code here 
    ...
except Error as err:
     print(str(err))
```